# Can't receive video on webrtc when I toggle camera

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs, rtcpeerconnection

I'm trying to write a method to toggle camera for turn on/off the camera.

Call Peer

```
const callPeer = (myPeer, peerId, myVideoStream, addToCalls = true) => {
    const call = myPeer.call(peerId, myVideoStream);
    if (addToCalls) {
        let existingCall = myPeer.calls.find((existingCall) => existingCall.peer == peerId);
        if (existingCall)
            myPeer.calls.splice(myPeer.calls.indexOf(existingCall), 1);
        myPeer.calls.push(call);
        call.on('stream', peerVideoStream => {
            let userVideoElement = $("video[data-peer='" + peerId + "']")[0];
            userVideoElement.srcObject = peerVideoStream;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer Call

```
const answerCall = (call, addToCalls = true) => {
    call.answer(myVideoStream);
    if (addToCalls) {
        let existingCall = myPeer.calls.find((existingCall) => existingCall.peer == call.peer);
        if (existingCall)
            myPeer.calls.splice(myPeer.calls.indexOf(existingCall), 1);
        myPeer.calls.push(call);
    }
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
        let userVideoElement = $("video[data-peer='" + call.peer + "']")[0];
        userVideoElement.srcObject = userVideoStream;
    });
}
```

Toggle Camera

```
const toggleCamera = async (isOpened, peerId, isMuted) => {
    let oldStream = myVideoStream;
    myVideoStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: !isOpened,
        audio: true
    });
    myPeer.calls.forEach((call) => {
        call.peerConnection.removeStream(oldStream);
        call.peerConnection.addStream(myVideoStream);
    });
    oldStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        track.stop();
    });
    let myVideoElement = document.querySelector("video[data-peer='" + peerId + "']");
    myVideoElement.srcObject = myVideoStream;
    myVideoElement.muted = true;
    if (isOpened)
        $("#video").removeClass("bg-primary").attr("data-video", "closed");
    else
        $("#video").addClass("bg-primary").attr("data-video", "opened");
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        type: isOpened ? "video-off" : "video-on"
    }));
    if (isMuted)
        myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
};
```

When I print the localstream at peer connection, it seems like localstream is switched but when I print the remote stream from other client, Its not changing. So stream event is not runnig.

I also tried to write a event for onaddstream but it also didn't work.